# Collecting the NonZero pixels for all different contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to sort the contours according to a sequence (the sequence doesn't matter here). I have a very small question, which is the right numpy array that I should pass in the below code snippet for which I get right row/col (nonZero) pixels simultaneously.

```
row_pixels=cv2.countNonZero(blur[cy][:])

col_pixels=cv2.countNonZero(blur[:,cx])
```

What I was doing gave results like below: For all the 5 contours I get nearly the same amount of non zero pixels, I realize this is because I am passing the "entire" image (as you see above blur is the entire image) as the numpy array for calculating the pixels which is wrong and I realize that.

Current Input: The below image (without markers)

Expected Output: For all the 5 contours, row/col (NonZero) pixels.

What i am doing currently is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours 
import imutils 
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import time

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Object Detection and Tracking using YOLO in OPENCV')
parser.add_argument('--image', help='Path to image file.')

args = parser.parse_args()
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX


start=time.time()
im_in = cv2.imread(args.image, 0)
_, thres2=cv2.threshold(im_in, 140, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
dilate = cv2.dilate(thres2,None)
erode = cv2.erode(dilate,None)

im_3=erode.copy()

blur=cv2.medianBlur(im_3,5)

a=[]
r=[] 
row_col_pixel_values=[]
cl=[]
data=[]
global mainar
#find contours 
_,contour2,_=cv2.findContours(blur,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# print(contour2)
for c in contour2:
    area=cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area>10000 and area <30000:
        a.append(area)

        cv2.drawContours(blur, [c], 0, (128, 128, 128), 1)


        M=cv2.moments(c)
        cx=int((M["m10"]/M["m00"]))
        cy=int((M["m01"]/M["m00"]))
        center =(cx,cy)
        data.append((cx,cy))
        cv2.circle(blur,(cx,cy), 5,(128,128,128),-1)
        print("",cx,cy)
        print(len(blur[cy][:])) 
        # one=blur[c]
        row_pixels=cv2.countNonZero(blur[cy][:])

        col_pixels=cv2.countNonZero(blur[:,cx])
        comb=(row_pixels,col_pixels)
        cl.append(comb)

nparea=np.array(a)
npcentercoord=np.array(data)

row_col_pixel_values=np.array(cl)
print("Area of 5 contours :",nparea)
print("Center coordinates of 5 contours:",npcentercoord)

print("Row and Column pixel values of 5 contours:",row_col_pixel_values)

mainar=np.column_stack((nparea,npcentercoord,row_col_pixel_values))
# print(mainar)

mainar[:,[1]] = (mainar[:,[1]]).astype(int)

MinX = int(min([_[1] for _ in mainar]))
MinlowerX = (MinX - 10) 
MinupperX = (MinX + 10)
MinY = int(min([_[2] for _ in mainar]))
MinlowerY = (MinY - 10) 
MinupperY = (MinY + 10)
MaxX = int(max([_[1] for _ in mainar]))
MaxlowerX = (MaxX - 10) 
MaxupperX = (MaxX + 10)
MaxY = int(max([_[2] for _ in mainar]))
MaxlowerY = (MaxY - 10)
MaxupperY = (MaxY + 10)

print("", MinX,MinY,MaxX,MaxY)


def PixeltoNumeric(channel,rowMM,colMM):

    if channel=="4S":
        for i in range(0, len(mainar[:,1])):
            cx=mainar[i,1]
            cy=mainar[i,2]
            if (cx in range(MinlowerX,MinupperX+1)) and (cy in range(MinlowerY,MinupperY+1)):
                rowp=mainar[i,3]
                colp=mainar[i,4]
                print("The center coordinates(x,y) and (Row/Col) pixels of 4Schannel: ")
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in row:".format(rowMM/rowp))
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in col:".format(colMM/colp))
                print(cx,cy,rowp,colp)

    if channel == '1':
            for i in range(0, len(mainar[:,1])):
                cx=mainar[i,1]
                cy=mainar[i,2]
                if (cx in range(MaxlowerX,MaxupperX+1)) and (cy in range(MaxlowerY,MaxupperY+1)):
                    rowp=mainar[i,3]
                    colp=mainar[i,4]
                    print("The center coordinates(x,y) and (Row/Col) pixels of 1Channel: ")
                    print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in row:".format(rowMM/rowp))
                    print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in col:".format(colMM/colp))
                    print(cx,cy,rowp,colp)

    if channel == '2':
        for i in range(0, len(mainar[:,1])):
            cx=mainar[i,1]
            cy=mainar[i,2]
            if (cx in range(MinlowerX,MinupperX+1)) and (cy in range(MaxlowerY,MaxupperY+1)):
                rowp=mainar[i,3]
                colp=mainar[i,4]
                print("The center coordinates(x,y) and (Row/Col) pixels of 2Channel: ")
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in row:".format(rowMM/rowp))
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in col:".format(colMM/colp))
                print(cx,cy,rowp,colp)

    if channel == '3':
        for i in range(0, len(mainar[:,1])):
            cx=mainar[i,1]
            cy=mainar[i,2]
            if (cx in range(((MinlowerX+MaxlowerX)//2),((MinupperX+MaxupperX+1)//2)) and (cy in range(((MinlowerY+MaxlowerY)//2),((MinupperY+MaxupperY+1)//2)))):
                rowp=mainar[i,3]
                colp=mainar[i,4]
                print("The center coordinates(x,y) and (Row/Col) pixels of 3Channel: ")
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in row:".format(rowMM/rowp))
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in col:".format(colMM/colp))
                print(cx,cy,rowp,colp)

    if channel == '4N':
        for i in range(0, len(mainar[:,1])):
            cx=mainar[i,1]
            cy=mainar[i,2]
            if (cx in range(MaxlowerX,MaxupperX+1)) and (cy in range(MinlowerY,MinupperY+1)):
                rowp=mainar[i,3]
                colp=mainar[i,4]
                print("The center coordinates(x,y) and (Row/Col) pixels of 4NChannel: ")
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in row:".format(rowMM/rowp))
                print("1 pixel has {:.5f} many mm in col:".format(colMM/colp))
                print(cx,cy,rowp,colp)

    return (cv2.imshow("4",blur))


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Input Image]
[image: Expected Output(The number of pixels are wrong here)]
[image: Simple Illustration of the contours]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understand you correctly but my understanding is that you want to find all coordinates (x,y) of the pixels within all contours. If this is your question, you can achieve that with the following code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im_in = cv2.imread(r'image.png', 0)
_, thres2 = cv2.threshold(im_in, 140, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
dilate = cv2.dilate(thres2, None)
erode = cv2.erode(dilate, None)
im_3 = erode.copy()
blur = cv2.medianBlur(im_3, 5)

# I am using OpenCV 4 therefore it returns only 4 parameters
contour2, _ = cv2.findContours(blur, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
extracted = np.zeros(blur.shape, np.uint8)

for c in contour2:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    # I have modified these values to make it work for attached picture
    if 10000 < area < 300000: 
        cv2.drawContours(extracted, [c], 0, (255), cv2.FILLED)

contour_x, contour_y = np.nonzero(extracted)

plt.imshow(extracted, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

This is the extracted [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW69Y.png).

## Update 1

After your explanation, I understand that you want to calculate the width and height of each separate contour. Based on your provided sample code, I assume that you want to measure width and height using the line crossing the center of the contour. You can achieve that by drawing and measuring the contour on the clear image. See the code below:

```
# I am using OpenCV 4 therefore it returns only 4 parameters
contour2, _ = cv2.findContours(blur, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
extracted = np.zeros(blur.shape, np.uint8)
contoursSize = []
for c in contour2:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    # I have modified these values to make it work for attached picture
    if 10000 < area < 300000:
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        cx = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]))
        cy = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
        extracted.fill(0) 
        cv2.drawContours(extracted, [c], 0, 255, cv2.FILLED)
        width = cv2.countNonZero(extracted[cy][:])
        height = cv2.countNonZero(extracted[:, cx])
        contoursSize.append((width, height))
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, I was actually trying to calculate the width and height of each of these contours as you extracted in the image(From the center). So currently what i get for the row/col pixels is the entire image's non Zero pixels. I was hoping to calculate these pixels WITHIN each contour :                                                                                          "row_pixels=cv2.countNonZero(blur[cy][:])"- this gives for the entire image and not for one contour . Do I make sense ?

Comment: If you need the width and height of those contours, you can use the function cv2.boudingRect to get the bounding box for contour. Check this code:
`for c in contour2: rect = cv2.boundingRect(c); print(f'width: {rect[2]}, height: {rect[3]}')`

Comment: I cant use the bounding rectangle because you see the center contour is an inward shaped curve. The width would not be measured correctly through that process. Thats why i shifted to counting white pixels inside the contours.

Comment: I have edited my post based on your explanation. This is not the best solution in terms of performance, hence it could be implemented without drawing, just by processing points from the contour, but this one is a quick win.

Comment: A small question though , when i cv2.imshow("",extracted) , why do I only see one white contour ? . I get the approach of yours , you created a black mask over the original image and count the white pixels over the 5 white contours using cv.FILLED . But when i get the output of the image , i only see 1 white contour , though i get the results ? Am i doing something wrong :(